# MySQL: What effect does DEFINER have on procedures and functions?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I use SQLyog to write procedures and functions in a remote MySQL database I am developing. The database has only one username/password. It is accessed via a front end executable application that I have written in Delphi and which is used by a couple of dozen different people, all using the same username.

When I use SQLYog to write a procedure using, for example,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE age_frequency_count(IN bin_size INT)
```

The resulting procedure gets the definer put in whether I like it or not, resulting in

```
CREATE DEFINER=<the_user_name>@<my_IP_address> PROCEDURE age_frequency_count(IN bin_size INT)
```

(I think this is being done by MySQL, not by the SQLYog DBMS.)

From reading the documentation and from posts here on SO, I have a rough, but rather confused idea of how the definer is used to say what permissions are needed to execute, or maybe alter, the procedure and what the procedure is allowed to do, but I would welcome some clarification.

**Question**

If my IP address is in the definer, can the procedure still be **executed** by other people who will be logging in from a different IP address (although with the same username)?

Can someone please clarify what the definer is doing? i.e. what can a connection from my IP address do that connections from other IP addresses can't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the `DEFINER` clause to create a stored procedure with the security privileges of a powerful user that also has `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT`, and `INSERT` rights to a particular database table. Then, I only grant `EXECUTE` on that stored procedure to a *minon* user (some people call it a *www* user, versus the more powerful *wwwproxy* user).

In this way, the *minion* can only execute designated stored procedures and has no `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT`, `INSERT`, or other rights on a database table.

I hope that helps frame the idea behind the DEFINER clause. Use it to separate *power* from *tasks*.

You are correct, by default, MySQL uses the identity of the current user as the `DEFINER` when creating a stored procedure. This identity could be the identity of the front-end application (so to speak), or, like I said, you can use a *proxy user* that has normal table privileges. Then the application user would be the `minion` with only one privilege on the stored procedure, `EXECUTE`.

In short, if the default `DEFINER` user does not represent what the front end application uses to login to the database, and you want it to, then you need to change the stored procedure with `ALTER`, if possible.

On the other hand, the better idea would be to use the minon/proxy scenario. Application users on the Internet have no bearing on the IP that ends up in the stored procedures `DEFINER` clause. All that matters is the IP of where your app is logging in from to MySQL. Your app is talking to the database, not user agents on peoples' computers. However, that notion is, generally, a point of initial confusion. You are fine!

Hope that helps.

Comment: You have not answered the question around the IP addresses. On the definer question this answer is spot on.

Comment: @Shadow My computer crashed. Sorry! :-)

Comment: This database only has one user so my procedures/functions can only perform operations that user is able to do. But are you saying that once it is written, anyone who uses my procedure/function will be able to do whatever that procedure requires (as we are all effectively the same user)?  What about the IP address bit in the definer? Will that prevent users with other IP addresses from executing it?

Comment: The order of operations is this. *Visitors* from the Internet contact your application / middleware (Delphi), then your application's sole MySQL user account is used to login and EXECUTE the stored procedure. The Internet *visitors* do not gain explicit privileges to do anything, and their IP address are not a factor. It's your application, by virtue of logging with the correct account, from the correct IP, and with the correct password, that has the privilege to EXECUTE the stored procedure.  **Whatever** that sole MySQL user account can do, all who can login with that account can do.

Comment: So the IP address bit is irrelevant then?

Comment: Thus, be careful about SQL injection, because if that single account can `DROP` tables and your application is vulnerable, then you could have a bad situation. That's why a two account system is better. :-)

Comment: @user3209752 Correct. IP addresses of individual clients running user agents are irrelevant in terms of your application logging in and doing whatever it is designed to do.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now, thanks. SQL injection probably is not likely as all my users 'own' the data in the database so it would be pointless anyone deliberately injecting a drop command as they would simply delete all their own data.